# I have hardware Virtualization Enabled, Hypervisor switched off, Still shows HAXM - Does not Support Virtualization Error

Tags: android, virtualization, intel, hyper-v, haxm

I have enabled Virtualization from BIOS.
I checked the Hyper-V and disabled it and have "hypervisor off" option
 from cmd prompt after using bcdedit function.
![enter image description here][1]
Im still getting the HAXM Error when i run the haxm-android.exe.

SecurAble says that my pc supports Hardware Virtualization .
![enter image description here][2]

I dont Have avast installed nor any other Antivirus.

I have AMD fx 8350 OctaCore.

Please tell what should i do?
I have scouted many forums but all have the same above solutions.
Nothing seemed to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haxm only works on Intel processors.